# Why GraphQL error: createReadStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to upload a file using apolloclient and GraphQL and I'm getting GraphQL error: createReadStream is not a function. Don't know how to fix it

```
Mutation: {
        uploadFile: async (parent, { file }) => {
            const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file

            const stream = createReadStream()
            const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `/public/images/${filename}`)
            await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathName))

            return {
                url: `http://localhost:3000/images/${filename}`,
            }
          },
}
```

Comment: request body fragment?

Comment: Seems like you did not import `fs` correctly? What does `fs` like at that point? Try printing it to the console or using debugging tools to check the functions closure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading my nodejs to 12.0.0

> nvm install 12; nvm use 12

If you're in windows, you have to install nvm for windows from [this repository](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

Also you have to use add these lines in you package.json file in the server side

```
"resolutions": {
"graphql-upload": "11.0.0"
```

},

And `"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"` under scripts in the same file

run `nvm install`

and then start your server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a different version of node. I encountered this issue too and I figured out that you just need to set up graphql-upload
https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload